# Как выразить регрессионную модель, построенную при помощи RandomForestRegressor, через формулу чтобы это можно было использовать для предсказаний?

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn

В обычной линейной регрессии мне все понятно - вывел интерцепт построенной модели, коэффициенты для независимых переменных и составил классическое уравнение линейной регрессии, которое можно применять на практике.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как при помощи RandomForestRegressor достигнуть аналогичного результата?
Модель в виде "черного ящика" это уже не плохо, но хотелось бы понять как через независимые переменные можно достичь желаемой величины зависимой переменной.
Почитал документацию, а там кроме R2 и feature_importances_ больше ничего похожего на бета-коэффициенты регрессии не нашел. Или я что-то не так понимаю.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, пример с линейной регрессией хороший, однако, случайный лес имеет гораздо более сложную структуру.

`RandomForestRegressor` -- ансамбль (т.е. композиция) из `n_estimators` `DecisionTreeRegressor` моделей.

Каждое дерево после задания гиперпарамеров делает предсказание для нового наблюдения. Делает оно предсказание согласно первой прикрепленной картинке (только там задача классификации). При каждом split'е (разбиении), пытаясь уменьшить дисперсию в выборке (на самом деле, все чуть сложее, можете почитать тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/116385/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как новый сэмпл попал в определенный лист дерева, оно предсказывает, например, усредненное значение target'а из этого листа (самая простая эвристика).

Лес, получив предсказания всех деревьев, может, например, снова усреднить их (в контексте задачи регрессии) и выдать финальное предсказание (опять же, это самая простая эвристика)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже очевидно, что подход гораздо более серьезный в сравнении с `LinearRegression`, так что описать предсказание одной единственной формулой вряд ли удастся (если я ошибаюсь, прошу коллег поправить)

Comment: elderberry17, благодарю!